# Getting Mapnik v2.2.0 for windows 32 bit to work with Pycairo

Tags: python, cairo, mapnik, pycairo

Have installed Mapnik and Python but on running the python demo get the message

```
Pycairo not available...will render Cairo formats using alternative method.
```

After that python crashes. I have installed Python 2.7 and it is working from both command line and Windows GUI, I have downloaded and placed Cairo 1.12.2 and pycairo 1.10.0 at the root of `C:\` and added these to the path.

Has anyone else has been in this situation and found a fix?...

Comment: You have to _install_ `pycairo`, not just download it and place it on your path.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to [Pycairo not available #2531](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/2531) which is opened 26 days ago,

**"You are not doing anything wrong - instead you are hitting a limitation in the packages. Mapnik - to work with pycairo - requires having its python bindings compiled against pycairo headers."**

and

[Remove pycairo usage from rundemo.py #2533](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/issues/2533) 
in 
[commit](https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/commit/520bab27be88cacd4e749d00af7a716a638d5392)